# Devise redirect after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Devise is giving me a pretty hard time. For now, everything else seems to be working, except the sign up redirect. I want devise to redirect to my town controller at index action, upon sign up or login (login actually works).

I've tried overriding RegistrationsController and i've tried adding an applicationsController function like :

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if resource_or_scope.is_a?(User)
      town_path
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Still, i'm getting the same error :

```
NoMethodError in User/townController#index

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.*
```

Seriously, i cannot find a way to do it. Any ideas please ? :)

EDIT : MY ROUTES

```
      new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
          user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
  destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
         user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
     new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
    edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                 {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                       PUT    /users/password(.:format)                      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
     user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                       PUT    /users(.:format)                               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                       DELETE /users(.:format)                               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                  root        /(.:format)                                    {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
             user_root        /user(.:format)                                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"user/town"}
                  home        /home(.:format)                                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
                  town        /town(.:format)                                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"town"}
                 inbox        /messages(.:format)                            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"messages"}
                 inbox        /messages/inbox(.:format)                      {:action=>"inbox", :controller=>"messages"}
```

Routes.rb :

```
  devise_for :users

  root :to => "home#index"

  namespace :user do
    root :to => "town#index"
  end  

  scope :path => '/home', :controller => :home do
    match '/' => :index, :as => 'home'
  end

  scope :path => '/town', :controller => :town do
    match '/' => :index, :as => 'town'
  end
......
```

Comment: Show us your routes via `$ rake routes` please

Comment: Thanx, i added the relevant routes

Comment: Show us your devise directive inside your routes.rb. From the looks of it, the resource is not a User. Figure out which class it actually is.

Comment: Interesting - I got after_sign_in_path_for(resource) to work ONLY when I added it into application_helper.rb rather than in the controller. ALthough the docs say to override the controller method, it appears you actually need to override the application helper method, which is what is being called.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I got this working.

```
# In your routes.rb
match 'dashboard' => 'user_dashboard#index', :as => 'user_root'
```

Then make sure you don't have a `before_filter :authenticate_user!` set on your `home#index` controller.

Comment: Since Devise 1.2.rc, there has been a preferred way to achieve this in Devise Wiki https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29    http://stackoverflow.com/a/6402730/544068

Answer (score 16):

Im using Devise 1.3.4 with Ruby On Rails 3.0.7. After checking out the internet for a solution, what i did was simply pasting the following code

**first)**To redirect after a succesful sign up to the welcome page,place in /config/routes.rb the following (note, replace `:user` with the argument you provided to `devise_for`):

```
namespace :user do
root :to => "welcome#index"
end
```

**second)**To redirect after a sign out (to the welcome page also), place in the /app/controllers/application_controller.rb this method:

```
private
# Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
welcome_index_path
end
```

This worked for me, i hope it does for all of you.

Answer (score 14):

An answer to this question that worked perfectly for me is explained on the Devise Wiki here:
[How To: Redirect to a specific page on successful sign up (registration)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29/)

Answer (score 7):

Since no one is answering I'll chime in. Are you sure this is the code that's causing the error? Your `resource_or_scope` being nil makes it seem like Devise is the problem but I doubt that's the case. So I think the problem is somewhere else.

I'd try the following just to make sure it works first.

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    "http://www.google.com"
  end
```

If that does work then try checking the `resource` variable to make sure it's not nil.

Comment: hello, i've actually tried the exact same code before and it works on login only. But not on logging in after signing up.

Comment: From Devise wiki *After signing in a user, confirming the account or updating the password, Devise will look for a scoped root path to redirect. Example: For a :user resource, it will use user_root_path if it exists*. I see you have a `user_root` in your routes. Is that where it's ending up?

Comment: I have   namespace :user do
    root :to => "town#index"
  end and it indeed ends in town/index on signing in. However, when a new user signs up and is logged in(devise default behaviour), i get the error above (still it redirects to town/index, but with that error, which seems like i don't have the current_user object).

Answer (score 3):

What Tony said. Namespace is not meant to be used this way. I don't know who came up with this hack that doesn't work at all, but unfortunately, it's one of the very first solutions that come up when googling.

```
namespace :user do
  root :to => "town#index"
end
```

sets '/user' as the user_root_path and points to the index action of 'user/town' controller which you don't have. What you have is 'town' controller. And that's why you got the error. What you need is

```
get '/town', to: 'town#index', as: 'user_root'
```

This way, '/town' points to 'town#index' and is set up as your user_root_path, which is what Devise redirects to after user

1. sign in
2. sign up
3. update password

so you do not even need to override `after_sign_in_path_for`, which, contrary to what many believe, is not the best place to tackle the devise redirect problem.

*on Rails 4.1+ and Devise 3.2*

Comment: WEll you are kinda right. we need to edit your `as: 'user_root'` with the quotes and ensure you don't use `towns_path` anywhere or you'll need to change them too, as you'll error on any use of that helper in your app.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried overwriting devise `sign_in_and_redirect` method; It will work for you

```
def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope,resource)
    if resource_or_scope == :user
      redirect_to town_path
    else
      super
    end
end
```

Comment: added that to my custom registrations controller, but still getting the same error :/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful or not but I ran into the same problems above but difference is I'm using a custom registrations controller.

From the devise source code for RegistrationsController it appears it is calling sign_in_and_redirect which in turns passes it to redirect_location method.

I override the redirect_location to just return the path from after_sign_up_path_for(resource) rather than stored_location_for(scope) || after_sign_up_path_for(resource).

Within after_sign_up_path_for(resource), I customise the method to redirect to the right path based on the type of user

Works in Rails 3.0.5 and Devise 1.3.0 for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Devise bypasses `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` when signing into a resource that has just been created. What you need is `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)`:

```
# override in your ApplicationController or custom Devise::RegistrationsController  
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  if resource.is_a?(User)
    town_path
  else
    super
  end
end
```

You'll still need your `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` override  to correctly redirect subsequent sign ins to the resource.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Eventually resorted to if statement in application controller. If user signed in and they do not have a profile then route to the new_profile_path

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to the other great input; one thing you may overlook, in case you are using the `confirmable` attribute with your models, is that *inactive* accounts use a different method if you want to alter the `after_sign_up_path`, as documented on the devise wiki: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29.

In this case, use:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected
    def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      '/an/example/path'
    end
end
```