# Log In - if Admin direct to Admin Index 1st

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, hyperlink

I have the 'user' log-ins all set up and working. I would like to change it so that when an Admin or Moderator logs in - they are directed to the /admin/index page 1st so they can preview new posts?

Would also like to add a 'Home' link for all 'users' to sit neatly beside the 'sign in' and 'sign up' links, not sure how I do it in this code block?

Any code solutions would be appreciated...

```
views/layouts/application.html.erb

<div id="user_nav">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
        <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %> or
        <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the home link before or after the if/else/end block:

```
<div id="user_nav">
    <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
        <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %> or
        <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="user_nav">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
        <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %> or
        <%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
</div>
```

As for directing the Admin or Moderator to a different page on signup, you could detect a user's role in the controller that handles `new_user_session_path` and redirect_to `/admin/index` if they are that type of user.

Comment: The new_user_session_path is handled in views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb. Any suggestions for the code and where I add it?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear @ubique, I mean you can tap into the code at the controller level to do custom actions like redirecting. Take a look at custom controllers here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. These answers also offer ways to customize the redirects after sign-in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987841/devise-redirect-after-sign-up

Comment: Your links helped, but I'm still stuck with the code I need to use... have posted above if anyone can help/edit?