# How do I create the users root path route using the Devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I did a search and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987841/devise-redirect-after-sign-up) on SO, but the accepted answer doesn't seem to be working for me. Basically, the Divise wiki says...

> After signing in a user, confirming the account or updating the
>   password, Devise will look for a scoped root path to redirect. For
>   instance, for a :user resource, the user_root_path will be used if it
>   exists, otherwise the default root_path will be used.

With my amateur knowledge of RoR, I have a devise model called Player, and I created the following statement in my routes.rb file...

```
match 'player_root', to: 'pages#play', as: :player_root, via: :all
```

...but with that, my app always redirects to my root path, instead of the players root path, which I defined above. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom! Also, I'm using Ruby 2 with Rails 4.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you are trying to specify `root_path` for `:players`.

If order to do that, you can use following:

```
authenticated :players do
  root to: 'pages#play', as: :authenticated_root
end
```

This will give you custom root_path for signed in users (players).

Answer (score 1):

Further to `Andrey Dieneko`, there are two other options you have:

> 1. Use `unauthenticated_path`
> 2. Use `authenticate_user!` in your controller

The bottom line here is that you may be thinking about incorrectly. You may be trying to work out where to take users *if* authenticated. However, you *may* be better suited to actually using the authentication methods in the controller to test whether the user is logged in, and if not route them to a login page:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "players#play"

#app/controllers/players_controller.rb
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

This will take a user to the "login" path if they are not logged in.

Alternatively, you can use `unauthenticated_path` like so:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "players#play"

unauthenticated do
   root to: "application#landing"
end
```

--

This method will only be best if you have an app like Facebook (IE it has no "landing page" etc)

I think `Andrey's` answer is more apt (especially if you have a landing page)