# Devise not redirecting to specific location after sign UP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I've been trying to make Devise redirect my rails app to a **profile_new_path**  location after signing up.

**So far I've...**

- Followed the instructions in the Devise documentation at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

  - As instructed I created a new file registrations_controller.rb and
    added the following code

*@app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb*

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    "/profiles/new"
  end
```

- I've tried using **new_profile_path**, change the argument "resource" to "user" and "profile"
- I've tried adding the same method in the application_controller.rb

It seems that no matter what I do Devise redirects me to profiles_path a path that I specified to be directed after sign_in in application_controller.rb

Can anyone provide some help on how to redirect to a specific path after sign_up. I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you add this in your routes.rb,

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987841/devise-redirect-after-sign-up) might help you.

I worked on similar one, where I redirected to welcome controller initially and then re redirect it to specific page based on the users authorization.